# How to get the navigation bar on view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have three View controller **A,B,C**.I have navigation controller attached to **A** view controller.In **A** i have some buttons,I have attached the button segue to **B** view controller.Onclick of the button i go to the **B** view controller.On **B** View controller i have **UITableView** on click of table view item i am launching the **C** view controller.below is the code for that

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath.row==0)
    {
        NSLog(@"first cell");
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
        UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BusinessCard"];
        [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];

    }
    else if(indexPath.row==1)
    {
         NSLog(@"second cell");


    }
    else if(indexPath.row==2)
    {
         NSLog(@"third cell");

    }

}
```

But on **C** view controller the navigation Bar is not appearing.I think C view controller is not linked to the Navigation Controller.

Comment: Use `[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES]` instead of `[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil]`

Comment: don't forget to mark an answer correct to close this question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `navigationController` push method to display navigation bar in C viewController

try this code:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
        UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BusinessCard"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Comment: Why my code is not working.Sorry but i am beginner in iOS

Comment: @deepakkumar you are using to present view controller. in present view controller there will not be a navigation bar

Answer (score 1):

Use the code below

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BusinessCard"];
UINavigationController *nav=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
[self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];
```

You need to present it using `UINavigationController` as modal.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am new to iOS.What is the difference between your answer & others answers above? @iphonic

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Push" segue and embed your ViewController in Navigation Controller, and then use its Navigation Controller's functions like `pushViewController` and `popViewControllerAnimated`

Answer (score 0):

Answer are all correct, but i just want to explain things..

```
//This line gets the storyboard with the name "Main" which contains all
//the setup you made for UI (User interface)
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];

//While this like gets the view inside your storyboard with
//storyboard ID/indentifier `BusinessCard `
UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BusinessCard"];

//Lastly, this line is correct presenting the viewcontroller BUT this doesn't add your
//viewcontroller to the array of viewControllers inside navigationController
//
//Also, this line makes you present the viewController above the 
//rootViewController of window which is in your case the navigationController
//
This is you Error
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];

//This is what you are looking for, and the correct one for your implementation
//
//This will let you add the `vc`(viewController) to the array of viewController 
//in navigationController, to confirm that you can check the `self.navigationController.viewControllers`
//which will return the array of viewController inside your navigationController
This is the Answer
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Hope this helps you, and my explanation is apprehendable.. Cheers